# You are running adb.exe. It is not compatible with PDANET

Tags: android-studio, adb, appium

I'm using a Samsung Galaxy J7 device and trying to use it to tether to my laptop using PDA Net application. I'm using android studio 2.1 and PDA Net version 4.19. I've enabled the USB Debugging option and also enabled the USB tethering option. I installed the PDA Net application on my system and it installed the app on my device also. Now both my device and laptop contain PDA Net version of 4.19(latest). Without Activating the USB tether option in the PDA Net application, when I try to run ADB devices option from the CMD prompt, I'm able to see my device listed. But when I try to enable the 'Activate USB Tether option in the PDA Net app on the phone and then connect the PDA Net option from the laptop tray, I end up getting the msg 'You are running adb.exe. It is not compatible with PDANET'. I believe that PDA Net downloads the device drivers to the system automatically. Please if anyone can help me on this.

Thanks,
Vishal S

Comment: How is this a programming question?

Comment: @KenWhite this is not directly. But indirectly it is because I prefer to test my android apps over wifi (I means not to use Cable) so PdaNet help to do so.

Comment: uninstall padNet+. solved